# ¿Cómo alinear al centro de la columna los botones?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

cómo puedo alinear al centro los botones, tendiendo al lado los dos select expandidos con un tamaño fijo de 15?? [image: Panel Vincular CMF a Consejo Popular]

Sorry, este es el código del contenido del body del diálogo:

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <b>Consejos Populares</b>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
        <select id="consejosPopulares" name="select_consejosPopulares">
            {% for cp in consejosPopulares%}
                <option value="{{cp.id}}">{{ cp.nombre }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>  
</div>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
        CMF Desvinculados
    </div> 
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
        CMF Vinculados
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
        <select id="cmfDesvinculados" name="select_cmfDesvinculados" multiple size="15">
            {% for cmf in cmfDesvinculados%}
                <option value="{{cmf.id}}">{{ cmf.title }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
        <div class="row">

        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <button id="btnVincular" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></button>
                <br/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <button id="btnDesvincular" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
        <select id="cmfVinculados" name="select_cmfVinculados" multiple size="15">

        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: porfavor publica tu codigo para que te puedan ayudar

Answer (score 1):

Una forma simple seria con CSS, creas un `div` al cual le agregas una `posicion absoluta` y dentro de este creas otro `div` con una `posicion relativa` (con respecto al `div padre`) y le agregas un `top: 50%` y un `left: 50%` y te deberia centrar el contenido

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
  <div style="position: absolute;"> 
    <div style="position: relative; top: 50%; left: 50%;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <button id="btnVincular" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></button>
          <br/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <button id="btnDesvincular" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero deberias colocar bien todos los cols. Y luego una vez que la suma de los hijos ocupen lo mismo que los padre, al contenido de lo que quieres centrar tienes que hacerle un `text-align:center;`.

```css
.centrado{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        Consejos Populares
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <select id="consejosPopulares" name="select_consejosPopulares" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <option value="cp1">CP Omaja</option>
        </select>
    </div>  
</div>

<div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        CMF Desvinculados
    </div> 
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        CMF Vinculados
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <select id="cmfDesvinculados" name="select_cmfDesvinculados" multiple size="15" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <option value="cmf1">CMF 10. Nigua</option>
        </select>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 centrado">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <p>
            <button id="btnVincular" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></button>
            </p>
            <p>
            <button id="btnDesvincular" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></button>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <select id="cmfVinculados" name="select_cmfVinculados" multiple size="15">

        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si no entiendo mal lo que vos queres es poner los botones btnVincular y btnDesvincular uno al lado de otro? Si es asi, tendrias que poner estos dos en una misma row y crear dos  con la mitad de las columnas es decir 6(recordando que bootstrap trabaja con 12 col) te dejo la solucion si es que es esta.
https://jsfiddle.net/15s4yw29/

Comment: Hola @Juanse Gimenez, no no es exactamente eso, tal vez la forma en que lo pregunté no es la correcta, los dos botones deben mantenerse uno debajo del otro, pero que estén a la mitad de la altura de los dos select múltiples !!!!!.